# What is the DBA function/tool called for keeping many remote DBs synchronized with a main DB

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration

I am a front-end developer being asked to fulfil some DBA tasks. Uncharted waters.

My client has 10 remote (off network) data collection terminals hosting a PostgreSQL application. My task is to take the .backup or .sql files those terminals generate and add them to the main DB. The schema for all of these DBs will match. But the merge operation will lead to many duplicates. I am looking for a tool that can add a backup file to an existing DB, filter out duplicates, and provide a report on the merge.

Is there a term for this kind of operation in the DBA domain?

Is this function normally built into basic DB admin suites (e.g. pgAdmin III), are enterprise-level tools required, or is this something that can be done on the command-line easily enough?

**Update**

PostgreSQL articles on DB replication [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) and [glossary](http://www.postgres-r.org/documentation/terms).

Comment: Basically, what you want is impossible (think about sequences being issued by the different sattelites) Take a look at datavault.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why it's impossible to merge a bunch of tables?

Comment: Assuming that you have some meaningful identifier for the primary key of each table, this isn't too bad.  If you were to try to use a meaningless sequential number for an ID in each table you would need a strategy for keeping them distinct.  Sometimes having a compound key with the combination of a machine ID and the sequence number can work for such cases.  Rather than forcing us to invent tables for an example, could you do so?  That will make it easier to provide a working example.

Comment: The thing is that I am not looking to code or solve the database problems per se. I am looking for an existing toolbox that will do it for me, and willing to pay. There is nothing special about the data that should require giving example tables. Just imagine that the 10 terminals are payments gateways with a catalogs that take in customer and transaction data.

Comment: Terminology you want is 'replication' where you can setup a master server to control this.  I'm not sure what Postgres has in this area (oracle and MSSQL will have these options...maybe MYSQL too), though I think Postgres 9.1 has some new code to support it...I think there might be a couple pieces of third party software capable of this.  Look up multi-master replication vs master-slave replication to pick out what you need.  There is probably a pure sql solution that just uses sql to compare rows from all sources and picking out which ones are unique.

Comment: Thank you @Twelfth, here is the postgres article on this subject - http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "merge a bunch of tables" but you could use Slony to replicate child tables (i.e. one partition per location) back to a master db.

This is not an out of the box solution but with something like Bucardo or Slony it can be done, albeit with a fair bit of work and added maintenance.